# Adding Range Check to EditText

Tags: android, filter, textview

I am trying to ensure the entered values are between 0 and 100.

So i set my filter:

```
myTextView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(0,100) });
```

based on code that is from a tutorial website.

However, it does **NOT** take into account that you can type at any place in the field.

Aka I can type **90.9**  then go back and **add 1 to the front** to make it **190.9**... It assumes the number is **90.91**.

Im thinking that the `end` `start`, `dend` and `dstart` have something to do with determining what the new string will look like.

Has anyone experience with this that could help please.

```
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            Double input = Double.parseDouble(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, Double c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around a bit with debugger and the values of end , start etc

Ive come up with this:

```
@Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            String newString = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart) + source.toString().substring(start, end) + dest.toString().substring(dend);

            Double input;
            // If we only have one char and it is a minus sign, test against -1:
            if (newString.length() == 1 && newString.charAt(0) == '-')
                input = -1d;
            else
                input = Double.parseDouble(newString);

            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }
```

This substrings the previous and new source. deleting or adding text in the correct place, to generate a preview of what it will become (`newString`). Then continues with check as normal.

This applies to deleting the entire thing in one go, or copy pasting new text. It determines what old text comes before it, the text inserted, then the text after it.